# using unity 3d models in android application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i am working on an **android AR application**. In this app the user can place 3d model of a furniture and interact with these. i want to design these model in unity 3d. I am using **vuforia sdk** for app development. i also downloaded the vuforia unity extension for this purpose. But i don't know anything about using unity. 
**Now the problem is that i'm not sure that i can use the unity model in my application?
If not then which software should i use for designing these 3d models?**

Comment: If you haven't done it already, check Vuforia forums too. There are Vuforia developers answering questions very frequently. Albeit it's possible you get some help here too.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is just a `Game Engine`. You can't use it to design your 3D models. You should use 3D modeling software such as **3Ds Max**, **Blender**, **Maya** to model your 3D furniture and then import them into Unity.

After this, you may use Vuforia plugin for Unity to create your Augmented Reality app. Using Unity with Vuforia is just drag-and-drop if your application is not that complicated.

Check [Vuforia Tutorial Series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WrEnREOT1F0). It's really easy to follow.